# Interference of two identical laser source

Tags: photons, laser, interference

Do two identical but separate laser sources cancel out each other when point on the same spot? By the way both light will be coming from same direction. And of course, they will have a phase difference of PI. Is there a video or documentation of such an experiment (or a similar one)?

Comment: Somewhat related: https://www.researchgate.net/publication/241779442_Two-laser_interference_visible_to_the_naked_eye Also, look for heterodyne interference and photomixing.

Answer (score 2):

For two perfect laser sources without noise (infinite narrow linewidth) and of same amplitude, you could achieve this when both sources have the same frequency and same polarization. You need to control the length of one pathway to control the relative phase to $\phi_0=\pi$:

$E=E_1+E_2=E_0 (sin(\omega t)+sin(\omega t+\phi_0))$

The problem in general will be that your source is subject to phase noise (neglecting amplitude noise at this place):

$E_1=E_0 sin(\omega t+\varphi_1(t))$

When you use independent lasers, these noise processes $\varphi_1(t)$ and $\varphi_2(t)$ are uncorrelated and won't cancel out:

$E=2 E_0 \cdot sin(\omega t)\cdot cos(\varphi_1(t)-\varphi_2(t)-\phi_0)$

If the two lasers had very little noise, this could work for some time. To synchronize the lasers, you would try to relate both laser noises (phase-locking).

Comment: You are right. However I wonder whether there is an experiment which shows this?

Comment: Microwave photonics deals with this issue. You have two laser sources with two frequencies slightly apart. On a photodiode, you want to generate a very pure RF signal which is exactly the difference of both laser frequencies. Your cosinus-term in the equation would become: $cos((\omega_1-\omega_2)\cdot t+\varphi_1(t)-\varphi_2(t)-\phi_0)$. You want the phase-terms $\varphi_1(t)-\varphi_2(t)$ to be negligible small.

Answer (score 1):

The simple answer is no, but that's because two separate laser beams cannot directly "com(ing) from same direction". Any two beams from separate sources which shine on a target with the centers aligned will have slightly different angles, and the distances from the emitter (and therefor the relative phase) will vary with location on the target. It's true that you can combine two beams with a beamsplitter, and theoretically get perfectly merged beams. In fact, this is the idea behind the [Michelson interferometer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Michelson_interferometer), which splits a single beam into two, then recombines them. The reason you normally see a fringe pattern on such an interferometer is one of practicality. As the Wiki article states,

> If there is perfect spatial alignment between the returning beams,
>   then there will not be any such pattern but rather a constant
>   intensity over the beam dependent on the differential pathlength; this
>   is difficult, requiring very precise control of the beam paths.

Since the alignment is so critical, it's just not worth taking the trouble for most setups. Also, with a standard fringe display you can see the effect of motion of the variable path length by observing the direction of motion of the fringes; a perfectly aligned system loses this information.

With that said, it is actually pretty easy to get effectively perfect alignment of an interferometer: use a retroreflector instead of a plane mirror for the moving target. Alignment accuracy of a few seconds of arc are fairly common, which is much better than is convenient with flat mirrors. Such retroreflectors are the heart of most laser distance measurement systems, but the apparent loss of motion direction information requires added complexity in the system to recover it. See [this paper](http://www.repairfaq.org/sam/laser/dmiprim.pdf) for a good overview.

Comment: Couldn't it be done using just a one-side mirror with 45 degree alignment? One laser directed at the panel can pass through. Other laser on the side can reflect through mirror. And there are no moving targets in this case?

Comment: @Nuri You're describing the final beam splitter of a [Mach-Zehnder interferometer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mach%E2%80%93Zehnder_interferometer), and that will indeed (if the relative phase is just right) cancel out all the output on one port, and send all the energy to the other port. If you displace the relative phase by $\pi$ the opposite combination happens.

Comment: @NuriTasdemir - Absolutely. My point was that the Michelson interferometer does exactly that - it uses the beam splitter to produce two effectively identical beams, and then combines them. If you do it just right, you get the situation you asked about. But it's hard to do it just right.

Answer (score 0):

It depends, if the frequency is identical and the waves are in the same phase, they do not cancel out. Only when the phase is exactly 1/2 out of phase, they will completely cancel out.(if you point them from the exact same location)
!http://cns-alumni.bu.edu/~slehar/PhaseConjugate/PhaseConjugate_files/image009.jpg

You can take a look here. This aren't two lasers, but i hope you understand what will happen if we change it too two lasers.
http://www.physicsclassroom.com/class/light/Lesson-1/Two-Point-Source-Interference

Comment: For the second link you gave, one can say that interference occurs because each photon is interacts with itself not necessarily with other photons.